# How to create crystalographic orientation map from indexed Kikuchi bands?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

Can somebody explain a detailed procedure, of producing orientation maps? I need to implement this into a software. Right now im able to transform EBSD pattern to probabilistic Hough space, get lines parameters - unfortunetly with some noised/wrong parameters too (any advices?), and autoindex this lines. What is the next step? I read lot of pdf's in the internet, but none explains this in details.
Sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of papers in the literature on how to do this.  One of possible relevance is C. Maurice & R. Fortunier, 'A 3D Hough transform for indexing EBSD and Kossel patterns', Journal of Microscopy 230, 520-529 (2008).

There are several open-source software packages out there that do it.  One is at ebsd-image.org, which includes links to other packages. Since it is open source, you can dive in and look at their algorithms.